# React: use set state to avoid stale state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I haven't found any similar implementations, so I'm wondering if this is a valid thing to do in React?

## Problems with useState

1. It's prone to stale value (which can happen in non-obvious ways).  Example [codepan](https://codepen.io/ryan200888/pen/PoVRYro).  Note the `oddCounter` is 0, because `counter` is stale.
2. It can't use async functions.

## Workaround

This workaround uses only the `setState` function.

```js
// Mutex
class Mutex {
  // Implementation omitted.  These can be easily implemented with an instance field of Promise that's resolved in unlock.
  lock = async () => {...};
  unlock = () => {...};
}

// Component
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const mutex = useRef(new Mutex());
  const handler = useCallback(async () => {
    await mutex.lock();

    let curCounter = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // Use setCounter as a "probe" to get the current counter.
      setCounter((v) => {
        res(v);
        return v;
      }
    });

    // Note: we can use async.
    curCounter += await getDelta();
    setCounter(curCounter);
    mutex.unlock();
  }, []); // Note dep list is empty, because this doesn't depend on counter

  return (<Button onClick={handler}>Click</Button>);
}
```

This may seem contrived, but the logic can be abstracted into a reusabled high-order function with "setState" as input.

This solves both the stale variable (we don't rely on "counter") and also allows using async.

There're some caveats with this approach:

1. Must use a mutex to prevent multiple function calls at the same time, otherwise `curCounter` might have race condition.  This may incur a performance hit.
2. Might need to deal with re-entrant locks.
3. Must remember to unlock, otherwise program will hang.

## Update

Thanks for everyone who responded.

**The async support is actually the main issue**.  Stale state can be fixed relatively easily.

Comment: The two examples you share could be better handled in other ways, but it's a bit hard to tell what the actual requirements are here. But the second example (the workaround) looks much to complicated.

Comment: I think when you refer to the `counter` being stale, that is actually just how react works. Each render has its own props and state, this means that when you click the button you execute the `handler` function which calls `increment` 10 times. In this render the `counter` is 0 no matter how many times you call it. 
Dan Abramov has a great article about this, which I highly recommend reading https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: @HenryWoody thanks.  Do you have suggestions of how to write async code that depends on the state's value?  The reason of the complication is to be able to use async calls like `await getNextDelta(counter)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `setOddCounter` within the call to `setCounter`, and then `increment` doesn't depend on either counter, so it never becomes stale.

```
increment = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCounter((v) => {
      if (v % 2 === 1) {
        setOddCounter((o) => o + 1);
      }
      return v + 1; 
    });
  }, []);
```

This doesn't let you use async, but that only matters if the previous state is required for the async action.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - `oddCounter` is derived from `counter`. Instead of using another state, recompute it on the fly. You can memoize it if the component re-renders due the changes other than the `counter`.

**Note**: `+(counter % 2 === 1)` evaluates to 0 (false) or 1 (true).

```
increment = React.useCallback(() => {
  setCounter(v => v + 1);
}, []);

const oddCounter = useMemo(() => counter.reduce(
  (sum, n) => sum + +(counter % 2 === 1), 0)
, [counter]);
```

Option 2 - use a `useEffect` to react to `counter` changes, and update `oddCounter`:

```
increment = React.useCallback(() => {
  setCounter(v => v + 1);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (counter % 2 === 1) {
    setOddCounter(v => v + 1);
  }
}, [counter]);
```

Comment: The [`useEffect` solution is not recommended](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state).